# Building strings with C preprocessor macros

Tags: c

The following code is from the C Puzzle book (chapter *Basic Types 1.1.*). I can't get it to work.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define PRINT(format,x) printf("x = %format\n",x)

int integer = 5;
char character = '5';
char *string = "5";

main(){
    PRINT(d,string); PRINT(d,character); PRINT(d,integer);
    PRINT(s,string); PRINT(c,character); PRINT(c,integer=53);
    PRINT(d, ( '5' > 5 ));

    {
        int sx = -9;
        unsigned ux = -8;
        PRINT(o,sx); PRINT(o,ux);
        PRINT(o, sx>>3); PRINT(o, ux>>3 );
        PRINT(d, sx>>3); PRINT(d, ux>>3 );
    }
}
```

The problem is the macro in the third line: `#define PRINT(format,x) printf("x = %format\n",x)`.

- Do current (standard-complying) C-preprocessors not support replacement inside string literals?
- Can you redefine the macro so the rest of the code works without any further changes?

Comment: The puzzling thing about that book is that they let it go to print with such broken code.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons Not puzzling at all... you can find books justifying the flat earth theory in the "science" section...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question really is whether *any* C preprocessor ever did replacement inside string literals.  I've never come across one.

What's required is a stringification, using `#`:

```
#define PRINT(format,x) printf(#x " = %" #format "\n", (x))
```

Comment: The C puzzle book outrightly claims the C preprocessor can do this, see p. 23.